# Why isn't parameter being passed properly in Verilog?

Tags: parameter-passing, verilog

I have two verlog modules as seen below. The parameter statement is supposed too allow me to pass the bus width i'd like to instantiate another module at.

I keep getting an error when trying to compile saying "Port expression 64 does not match expected width 1 or 2."

```
module LabL3;
parameter SIZE = 64;
reg [SIZE-1:0]a;
reg [SIZE-1:0]b;
reg c;
wire [SIZE-1:0]z;
integer i,j,k;
yMux #(SIZE) mux(z,a,b,c);

initial 
    begin
    for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)begin
        for(j=0;j<4;j=j+1)begin
            for(k=0;k<2;k=k+1)begin
    a=i;b=j;c=k;
    #1$display("a=%d b=%d c=%d z=%d",a,b,c,z);
            end
        end
    end
    end
endmodule
```

and the other file is:

```
module yMux(z,a,b,c);
parameter SIZE= 0;
output [SIZE-1:0]z;
input [SIZE-1:0]a,b;
input c;
yMux1 mux[SIZE-1:0](z,a,b,c);
endmodule
```

and lastly

```
module yMux1(z,a,b,c);
output z;
input a,b,c;
wire not_C, upper, lower;

not my_not(notC,c);
and upperAnd(upper,a,notC);
and lowerAnd(lower,c,b);
or my_or(z,upper,lower);

endmodule
```

and the command I am using is: iverilog LabL3.v yMux1.v yMux.v

I have tried the different syntax's for parameter passing.  All give the same result.
Any hints would greatly be appreciated.
- Chris

Comment: I tried to compile this on Altera's Quartus II. With LabL3 as top, a dummy output, dummy yMux1 and some dummy logic for everything(so it could actually compile into something). It compiled fine.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to inlcude yMux1.   If I understand the syntax correctly,  yMux #(SIZE) mux(z,a,b,c); should change the parameter SIZE in yMux1 to 64?

Comment: It should generate 64 instances of yMux1. Maybe fall back to using generate statement. Just in case. Generate is more explicit. Because the width of a,b and z differ from the width of c.

Comment: Which line is the error referring to?

Answer (score 4):

You are using vectored instances:

```
yMux1 mux[SIZE-1:0](z,a,b,c);
```

Where you end up with `SIZE` number of yMux1 instances. This should connect z,a,b bitwise correctly and connect the single bit `c` to all yMux1 c ports via replication.

If you really want to drive all c ports to the same value I would try manually replicating the port with:

```
yMux1 mux[SIZE-1:0](z,a,b,{SIZE{c}});
```

**[Example on EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2US) looks fine to me**. Could be an issue with the specific tool not supporting vectored instances correctly.

---

When possible I would recommend using named port connections (*ANSI header style*) from section 23.2.1 of the [SystemVerilog IEEE 1800-2012 Standard](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).

This style is very clear as to your design intent, I find it much easier to read which relates to less bugs. It also allows easier refactoring of the code due to the named connections and not being order dependent.

```
module LabL3;
  parameter SIZE = 64;
  reg  [SIZE-1:0] a;
  reg  [SIZE-1:0] b;
  reg             c;
  wire [SIZE-1:0] z;

  yMux #(
    .SIZE(SIZE)
  ) mux (
    .z(z),
    .a(a),
    .b(b),
    .c(c)
  );
```

yMux definiton:

```
module yMux #(
 parameter SIZE= 0
) (
 output [SIZE-1:0] z,
 input  [SIZE-1:0] a,
 input  [SIZE-1:0] b,
 input             c
);
// ...
endmodule
```

An example of the above code on [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Au).

Comment: Thank you,  but the problem I am having is that the parameter is not being set.  For instance in your above code I would get an error saying that " warning port (1) z of yMux expects 0 bits, got 64"   I just want to know why my parameter isn't being set.  Must all the modules be in the same file for it to work?

Comment: @kiwicomb123, no they do not have to be in the same file. [Here is my example working on EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Au).